# Making counsel-find-file not open dired on ./

Tags: ivy, counsel

I sometimes "accidentally" hit TAB again when I've already completed myself into a subdirectory. This means the current dir `./` is highlighted and ivy opens it with dired.

This is basically never ever ever what I want to do. I will do it one million times by accident for every time I actually *want* to open `./` with dired. So I rebound `TAB` from *ivy-partial-or-done* to *ivy-partial*. But this means ivy doesn't actually enter subdirs on TAB, it just completes them. This works, but forces an extra RET press every time I want to enter a subdir.

So what I basically want is the default behaviour, BUT have ivy special-case `./` by doing nothing. Is this possible?

Comment: Alternatively, you can retrain yourself to use `/` to enter directories instead of `TAB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be the best solution:

```
(setq ivy-extra-directories nil)
```

Not only will you not accidentally dired into `./`, it's not even displayed as a candidate. And `../` is redundant too because you can just use the keyboard shortcut for "up one level"